# How to calculate rowspans for a treelike structure representing a HTML table?

Tags: javascript, html, algorithm

Given the following example HTML table representing a 2D matrix of nodes with rowspans and colspans

```css
th, td { border: 1px solid black }
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="3">Major 1</th>
      <th rowspan="3">col4</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="2">Sub 1</th>
      <th rowspan="2">col3</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>col1</th>
      <th>col2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

*As you can see in the example there are some filler rowspans, e.g. for "col4". It needs to fill the remaining height*

This 2D matrix is dynamic, I need to calculate it based on a treelike structure coming from a configuration. The initial treelike structure for the example above would be

```
const columns = [{
  title: "Major1",
  children: [{
    title: "Sub1",
    children: [{
      title: "col1"
    }, {
      title: "col2"
    }]
  }, {
    title: "col3"
  }]
}, {
  title: "col4"
}];
```

In the first place I want to traverse this structure and calculate the colspans and rowspans for each node. For the colspan I thought the formula is

> colspan = sum of child colspans

but I couldn't figure out a formula for the rowspan yet. I started implementing the algorithm for colspans

```js
const columns = [{
  title: "Major1",
  children: [{
    title: "Sub1",
    children: [{
      title: "col1"
    }, {
      title: "col2"
    }]
  }, {
    title: "col3"
  }]
}, {
  title: "col4"
}];

function traverse(currentColumns) {
  for (const currentColumn of currentColumns) {
    currentColumn.colspan = 1;
    currentColumn.rowspan = 1;

    if (currentColumn.children) {
      traverse(currentColumn.children);

      currentColumn.colspan = currentColumn.children.reduce((totalColspan, childColumn) => totalColspan + childColumn.colspan, 0);
    }
  }
}

traverse(columns)

console.log(columns);
```

but don't know how to calculate the rowspans. Do you know the formula for rowspans?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Traverse the nodes and calc a node's deepness `level`, and a maximum level reached `maxLevel`.
- While traversing collect all items without children into an `items` array. These items can have `rowSpan` different from `1`. If you don't collect the items we have a performance hit because we need to traverse the nodes the second time to calculate `rowSpan`, so it's like a cache optimization.
- Loop through the `items` and calculate `rowSpan` as `maxLevel` minus a node's `level` plus `1`.

```js
let maxLevel = 0;
const items = [];

traverse(columns);

items.forEach(item => item.rowSpan = 1 + maxLevel - item.level);

console.log(columns);

function traverse(arr, level = 0){
  for(const item of arr){
    item.colSpan = 1;
    item.level = level;
    maxLevel < level && (maxLevel = level);
    if(item.children){
      item.rowSpan = 1;
      traverse(item.children, level + 1);
      item.colSpan = item.children.reduce((sum, child) => sum + child.colSpan, 0);
    }else{
      items.push(item);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script>
const columns = [{
  title: "Major1",
  children: [{
    title: "Sub1",
    children: [{
      title: "col1"
    }, {
      title: "col2"
    }]
  }, {
    title: "col3"
  }]
}, {
  title: "col4"
}];
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I think you can remove the parameter `parent`, no?

Comment: and would you mind explaining why you need a second collection `items`?

Comment: @baitendbidz yes, `parent` should be removed, a leftover, fixing

Comment: @baitendbidz added more description to the answer, describing `items` in more details

Comment: @baitendbidz you are also welcome to upvote the answer (the arrow up) if not done already ;-)